# How do I authenticate my external hard drive?

Tags: mac, backup, external-hard-drive, authentication, authorization

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 on my MacBook Air trying to move a directory/folder from my local disk to an external hard drive. But I get an error that says:

> **Modifying "Remote Disk" requires an administrator name and password**

> To move "`<your-folder>`", click Authenticate.

But I do not see any button or link labeled <kbd>Authenticate</kbd>. Also, [I read here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3565554?tstart=0) there might be a solution involving right-clicking the destination drive then selecting <kbd>Get Info</kbd> button. However, there is nothing there I can click.

So how can I move this folder to my external drive?

#### Full screen capture movie .gif

[image]

[Click here to see the full screen capture movie .gif.](https://ibb.co/jihRKF)

#### Step 1.

##### Here is where I get the error message after attempting to move the folder.

[image]

#### Step 2.

##### The 'Get Info' window is no help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an external hard drive. The external drive showed up in the Finder when I originally installed it but it went away after I clicked what I thought was a dropdown menu. I then proceeded under the assumption that the object that remained was what I was really looking for.

I had to reinstall the external drive by plugging it in to my USB. I could work on it successfully after reinstallation.